# How to implementing xamarin Forms Checkbox in list view for deleting checked rows only

Tags: xamarin, checkbox, cross-platform

I have a list view retrieving data from web api. i have added checkboxes to each row. now i want to delete only the checked rows. How can it be done?

My Xaml file:

```
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            <ListView x:Name="postsListView" ItemSelected="postsListView_ItemSelected" HasUnevenRows="True">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <!--Data From Web Api-->
                                <controls:CheckBox x:Name="checkbox2" x:Uid="{Binding Id}"  Checked="False" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
                                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Address}"/>
                                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding Telephone}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
```

I am unable to implement the listeners and the delete operations. i need to delete only selected checked rows.
MyXaml.cs File:

```
    private String Url = "http://192.168.8.115/NewAPI/api/Employee_Table";
    private HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    private ObservableCollection<Employee> _employee;
    Employee _Employee = new Employee();


    public AddRecordPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();            
    }

    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        var response = await client.GetStringAsync(Url);
        var Emp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Employee>>(response);
        _employee = new ObservableCollection<Employee>(Emp);
        postsListView.ItemsSource = _employee;
        base.OnAppearing();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a boolean poperty named IsChecked in the Employee model and you can set it to false initially for all the employees and bind it to Checkbox control. When the list item is tapped, you can code such a way that the IsChecked property of the selected item to true and vice versa. I believe you must have a button to delete the checked items and on click of the button, check for the IsChecked true employees in the collection and remove that. Let me know if any doubt.